# File Not Found When Running Docker Script But Is Found In Another Docker Script

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to run a script inside a docker that was published by google.
The command I use mounts some datafiles onto the docker in a file called '/input' (inside the docker).
When I run the script, it says that it does not find the input file.
However, I do use the -v flag, and I ran a script that makes sure the input file is there (inside the docker).
So in summary - when I run

```
find /input -name "*.fasta"
```

It outputs:

```
/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta
```

As needed, but when I run the script, it says

```
./dv-quick-start: 19: ./dv-quick-start: --ref=/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta: not found
```

---

Full Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
BIN_VERSION="1.0.0"
INPUT_DIR="${PWD}/quickstart-testdata"
DATA_HTTP_DIR="https://storage.googleapis.com/deepvariant/quickstart-testdata"
OUTPUT_DIR="${PWD}/quickstart-output"

sudo docker run \
  -v "${INPUT_DIR}":"/input" \
  -v "${OUTPUT_DIR}":"/output" \
  google/deepvariant:"${BIN_VERSION}" \
  find /input -name "*.fasta"

sudo docker run \
  -v "${INPUT_DIR}":"/input" \
  -v "${OUTPUT_DIR}":"/output" \
  google/deepvariant:"${BIN_VERSION}" \
  /opt/deepvariant/bin/run_deepvariant \
  --model_type=WGS \ **Replace this string with exactly one of the following [WGS,WES,PACBIO,HYBRID_PACBIO_ILLUMINA]**
  --ref=/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta \
  --reads=/input/NA12878_S1.chr20.10_10p1mb.bam \
  --regions "chr20:10,000,000-10,010,000" \
  --output_vcf=/output/output.vcf.gz \
  --output_gvcf=/output/output.g.vcf.gz \
  --intermediate_results_dir /output/intermediate_results_dir \ **This flag is optional. Set to keep the intermediate results.
```

Full output:

```
/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta
--ref is required.
Pass --helpshort or --helpfull to see help on flags.
./dv-quick-start: 19: ./dv-quick-start: --ref=/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta: not found
```

I feel there is some misunderstanding on my behalf, and I would appreciate any help.
Should more information be needed to answer the question, let me know.

Comment: Is the "Replace this string..." text part of your file?

Comment: Yes, it is a remainder of the instructions file that they published. However, since I need the WGS model_type, I left it as is. It is a valid input, so I don't see why it should be a problem though, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have some extraneous text in your shell script that's causing a problem.  Delete the "replace this string" and "this flag is optional" text and all of the whitespace before them, making the `\` the very last character on those lines.

In a shell script you can break commands across multiple lines using a `\`.  But, the `\` must be the absolute very last character in the line; if it's not, it escapes the character that comes after it.

```sh
# one line: ls -al $HOME
ls -al \
  $HOME

# two lines: ls -al " " more text here; $HOME
ls -al \    more text here
  $HOME
```

In your example you've left some explanatory text in

```sh
sudo docker run \
  ...\
  --model_type=WGS \ **Replace this string with exactly one of the following [WGS,WES,PACBIO,HYBRID_PACBIO_ILLUMINA]**

# This is seen as a separate command
  --ref=/input/ucsc.hg19.chr20.unittest.fasta \
  ...
```

Since the "Replace this string..." text makes the `\` not be the absolute last character in the line, it causes the shell to break the command.  You then get two commands, a `docker run` command without the `--ref` option and what looks like trying to run `--ref=...` as a separate command; that corresponds to the two errors you get.

Comment: Thank you very much @David Maze for taking time to write this great explanation, it worked :)